# Unable to retrieve the value from the database getting the error as "Unhandled exception type SQL Exception"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to get the role variable from the Database, I am getting error that "Unhandled exception type SQL Exception"

```
static int indexValue=0;
public static int getRole(IndexBean w){
    String elid= IndexBean.getId();
           conn = ConnectionProvider.getCon();

           Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
           ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT role FROM users WHERE elid = '" + elid + "'") ; 
           String role =  resultset.getString(1);
           if(role=="ADMIN"){
               indexValue = 1;
           }else if(role=="analyst"){
               indexValue = 2;
           }
           conn.close();
    return indexValue;
}
```

}

Comment: Unrelated, but: `role=="ADMIN"` is not doing what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method executeQuery(String) of Statement interface has a checked exception of SQLException.

In your snippet, the line

```
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT role FROM users WHERE elid = '" + elid + "'");
```

has a checked exception which is not handled. This is why you are getting the unhandled exception message. 
Whenever you are calling this method, you need to either put it in a try-catch block or add throws SQLException in the containing method signature.

[See Java Sql Statement API here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Yes, throwing the SQLException cleared my Issue.
Thanks :)